# Is there a open source firmware for any low end cell phone (non smart phone)?

Tags: firmware, mobile-devices

This question is about low end mobile phones which cost around $50 to $100, unlike Smart Phones like iPhone or the ones that support Android.

Nokia 1280, 1800 are some examples.

1. I want to customize the basic features such as Contacts, SMS in such a phone. So I either want a open source code of its firmware that is compatible with one or more of such phones, or I would like to know of a vendor who could sell a cell phone within this cost range along with the source code of the firmware?
2. Do these phones have any OS running in them? Or just a single threaded firmware program?

Answer (score 2):

The most advanced project in this field is [**OsmocomBB**](http://bb.osmocom.org/trac/).

Granted, finding the proper hardware is not easy, though not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I wish there were such a phone. As far as I can tell, no major phone manufacturer provides either the source for their firmware or the specs that you would need to write your own.
I think your best bet would be to take a look at open moko: http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Neo_FreeRunner_GTA02_Hardware

The freerunner is a smartphone that runs at about 400$
Since the full hardware spec is available here: http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Neo_FreeRunner_GTA02_Hardware
I think it may be possible to omit many of the parts that drive up the price, and make a derivative design that is simpler and cheaper.
eg, drop the wifi, gps, bluetooth, usb, and accelerometer.
However, I am not a computer engineer, so I'm not sure how difficult that would be, or if it would even be cheaper.

ref: [Custom Phone Firmware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393657/custom-phone-firmware)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ya, I have heard of OpenMoko. But $400 is too much for an average Indian. Are there cheaper models that support OpenMoko standards?

Answer (score 1):

I (think) get something intersanting for you: [motorola on sourcefroge](http://sourceforge.net/motorola/wiki/Projects/)

or [go to the page of the os](http://openezx.org)